# How do I increase the max length of captured Python parameters in Sentry?

Tags: python, django, sentry

I'm using `sentry-python==0.5.3` in a Django `1.11.6` project, and when I inspect a stacktrace's parameter list, I see some of the values are long enough to be cut off by a `...` elipsis. I want to see the entire value.

How do I configure `sentry-python` to show the entire parameter value in the stacktrace?

Here's how I'm calling the `init` function in my Django config:

```
sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="sentry dsn",
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration()],
    send_default_pii=True
)
```

Comment: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/377

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found this in the sentry-sdk Python source code, which makes me think it's not yet possible to configure this in the new SDK.

```
# TODO: read max_length from config
```

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/9f15a4027615d40cfdb37375233bc903d3cc753e/sentry_sdk/utils.py#L626

Comment: To provide some context, there are some limits serverside that this code is supposed to avoid. I think we can totally add a config for this on the client (feel free to open an issue) but you have to be aware that your value still might be trimmed on the server. Probably not to as little as 512 chars though.

Answer (score 15):

I just found this in the sentry-sdk python source code: 
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/0.12.2/sentry_sdk/utils.py#L36

and indeed:

```
sentry_sdk.utils.MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 8192 # undocumented truncation length as of v0.12.2
```

after `sentry_sdk.init` works as expected (the sentry web client displays the entire error message instead of `...` after the first 512 characters).

Note that, as @Markus Unterwaditzer mentions, sentry's server may still do some truncation, but I haven't encountered it with error messages ~5000 characters in length. Hopefully the stack trace and breadcrumbs get truncated before the error message itself.